# How important is the material/contact surface of a suction cup?

Tags: pressure

Smooth surfaces are best for effective suction cup performance. This is presumably so air can’t leak in and break the vacuum but what about the flexible cup - do we need a rough surface on the lip of the suction cup itself? If both surfaces are perfectly smooth then how can we evacuate air from the volume under the cup to begin with - or does the volume inside the cup actually increase upon depressing with air neither escaping or returning?

This is not how I’ve seen it explained but if this is correct then the lip of the cup (actually both surfaces) would need to be as smooth as possible. Or am I missing something altogether?

Answer (score 1):

both surfaces have to be as smooth as possible, in the beginning of your pressing down the air under the cup still can get out, do the volume of air decreases, the vacuum or very low air pressure under the cup ist what keeps it fast.

Answer (score 1):

Key to getting a suction cup to effectively stick is to have the lip of the cup made from compliant material. It will then conform to microscopic irregularities in the mating surface.

Larger irregularities will tend to locally push the cup lip up and out of contact with the mating surface over a nonvanishing distance, potentially creating a leak. Hence the cup lip must have a certain width to get a satisfactory seal with a rough or irregular surface.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Some additional research, the answer is that when depressing the Cup, pressure under the cup actually increases and the differential pushes a lot of the air out. Once equalized this transfer ceases but after the cup recovers shape, increases volume, the air expands and The pressure drops allowing atmospheric pressure to take over and hold the suction cup Tightly to the surface. This differential must be much less than the differential that Initially pushed the air out.

Answer (score 1):

A suction cup grips because atmospheric pressure pushes it against a surface,
and the seal is in contact only on a small part of the cup area.
So, smoothness and compliance of the seal material is important ONLY on
the load-bearing part of the area; the whole 'cup' can be a crude iron
hemisphere, as long as the contacting rim has a seal material which,
at the vacuum of interest, doesn't leak atmosphere into the evacuated center.
Such a seal is under the force of 1 atm times the area of the full
cup, but only touches the flat surface on a small seal-contact area.
The roughness of the surface determines the amount of pressure
required to establish a secure seal: the seal average
pressure equals the atmospheric pressure times the cup area, divided by
the seal contact area.

This is sometimes called the principle of unsupported area, and applies
to a variety of seal strategies.

Some molded suction cups are applied nearly flat, then deformed into
a cone-like shape to form the vacuum and seal.   If such a cup
is allowed to relax to flat, it comes loose because there's no longer
any unsupported (evacuated side of the cup) area.